# Spark SQL statement broadcast

Tags: sql, apache-spark

Is there a way to use broadcast in Spark SQL statement?

For example:

```
SELECT
    Column
FROM
    broadcast (Table 1)
JOIN
    Table 2
ON
    Table1.key = Table2.key
```

And in my case, Table 1 is also a sub query.

Answer (score 8):

Below is the syntax for Broadcast join:

```
SELECT /*+ BROADCAST(Table 2) */ COLUMN
FROM Table 1 join Table 2
on Table1.key= Table2.key
```

1. To check if broadcast join occurs or not you can check in Spark UI port number 18080 in the SQL tab.
2. The reason we need to ensure whether broadcast join is actually working is because earlier we were using the below syntax: 
   /* BROADCASTJOIN(Table2) */ which did not throw syntax error but in the UI it was performing sort merge join
3. Hence it is essential to ensure our joins are working as expected

Comment: Thank you for the solution. However, wouldn't it just hint the optimizer? What if we want to enforce it to perform broadcast?

Answer (score 7):

In Spark 2.2 or later you can use planner hints:

```
SELECT  /*+ MAPJOIN(Table1) */ COLUMN
FROM Table1 JOIN Table2
ON Table1.key = Table2.key
```