# Broadcast join in spark sql (Spark 1.6.2)

Tags: sql, apache-spark, join, spark-streaming

How to do broadcast in spark sql. There is query in which main table join with 10 lookup tables. I want to broadcast lookup table to reduce shuffling. How to do in sql statement. I can't broadcast df and create table. I need add broadcast only in query. I can easily do using spark scala, but I need to do in sql.

example-

```
select * from A a
join B b 
on a.id = b.id
join C c
on c.id = b.id
join D d
on d.id = c.id
.....
....
...
..
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark SQL statement broadcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45502457/spark-sql-statement-broadcast)

Comment: supported in spark 2.2. I am using spark 1.6

Comment: You could try adjusting the `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` setting?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Broadcast `hint` for the lookup tables:

```
select /*+ BROADCAST(b), BROADCAST(c), BROADCAST(d) */
* 
from A a
join B b 
on a.id = b.id
join C c
on c.id = b.id
join D d
on d.id = c.id
```

This will broadcast the lookup tables. However, please ensure that the lookup tables are less than `8GB` in size.

Answer (score 2):

Spark 1.x doesn't support [broadcast hints](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45502457) (hint syntax is valid, but has no effect).

If you want to use broadcasting you have do one of the following:

- Switch to `DataFrame` API.
- Adjust `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` below maximum expected size of a table.